# How to update only at the end of line only for the first line in 650 files all at once

Tags: notepad++

I have to update in 650 files.

Sample case
Example:

```
Apple 001
Mango 002
Banana 001
Grapes 003
```

Expected :

```
Apple 001|Red
Mango 002 
Banana 001
Grapes 003
```

Here  : `Red` is the appending text at the end of line.

Comment: What is your question? In notepad++ you can just write `|Red` behind `Apple001` to be honest.

Comment: Sorry. I have to update similar  change in 650 files and it tedious task ahead

Comment: Sorry for late answer but I guess there is no solution for notepad where you can handle that many files. Instead of this you can use powershell

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can do this with notepad++ with that many files.
But you can use powershell. If you are confident with powershell just use following code, if not feel free to ask me in comments.

`script.ps1`:

```
function appendToFirstLine($filepath){
    $file = Get-Content $filepath
    $file[0] += " TEXT TO APPEND"
    $file | Set-Content $filepath
}

cd C:\PATH\TO\FOLDER\OF\TEXT\FILES
Get-ChildItem -Path *.txt | %{ appendToFirstLine $_.FullName }
```

Explanation: The function `appendToFirstLine` "gets content" of a file and appends " TEXT TO APPEND" after the first line (`$file[0]`).
Then the script navigates to your folder with the files and uses it on every `*.txt` file in the folder.

Tip: If you have subfolders use `-Recurse` flag in the `Get-ChildItem`-Cmdlet.

In your case " TEXT TO APPEND" would be "|Red", but I highly recommend to copy some files and trying out if you don't want unwished blanks or similar. Furthermore if you execute the script twice, you also have "|Red|Red"